# Copied folder from Kali Linux becomes hidden folder with size zero in a Windows' partition

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, filesystems, kali-linux

I'm fairly new to file system's issues especially mounting a file system.
I've poked around and found no optimal solution
I've had Kali Linux on a partition with EXT4 or EXT3 (I'm not sure) and Windows on another. In order to install Ubuntu on Kali's partition and format it to EXT4 in the process, I've moved my files to the Windows partition in a folder called temp. After installing Ubuntu, the folder is normally accessed and all of it content from Ubuntu, but on Windows 7 side I see an empty folder with a size of zero, even if that partition is a Windows' partition.

What happened there and how do make that folder accessible under Windows again??

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you're using a secondary NTFS partition (not C:), as Windows may perceive unexpected changes to it's system drive as hardware failure or malware.  Probably best if the usernames on both Windows and Linux are the same. Create the folder you intend to share under Windows and give full control to 'everyone'.

Comment: So if I create a new NTFS partition, Windows will be able to read files placed in it? Even though I think you can explain how's that different from the original approach and how that guarantee that Windows will be able to read it. I think I'll be better off without messing around with partitions since I have already small ones filled with files, I can only move my files back to Linux, and try something else.

Comment: Only difference from original is that it's not the partition Windows is running on. Is your primary objective to get the files back into Windows, or are you trying to continue to share a file-system between both OS's?  Best solution either way, may be an external HDD or flash drive, as Windows expects them to go away and come back different.

Comment: Well for the purpose of simplification, I've omitted that the files are in a third partition, Windows is in C, Linux is in D, and files are in E wich is NTFS too, and yes optimally I'd like to keep the files shared between the two OS, otherwise I'd like them back to Windows.

Comment: do you have the same username on both Windows and Linux?  I'm using an external NTFS hard drive that I regularly write to from Linux (Debian 8), detach/attach to Windows and can both read and write from Windows. I just check the 'linux permissions' of files recently written by Linux to NTFS. Example: -rw------- 1 shughes shughes   231376 Jan 27 15:07 IMG_20180127_150745.jpg. Under Windows 7, properties for the same file show 'everyone' has full control. Note: the parent folders were originally created under Windows.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I've finally found a solution as easy as to create a folder under Windows on the same partition and copy files to it from the old folder.